# ColdFusion Consuming SSL Webservice with Multi Domain SSL

Tags: ssl, coldfusion, web-services

I'm trying to use a Webservice which is SSL secured with ColdFusion.

Now the following Error is occuring:

> Name in certificate `test.xyz.de' does
>   not match host name`service.xyz.de'

I've installed the SSL cert in ColdFusion using the keytool. How could I get this work?

Thx.

Comment: Do you have certificate for *.xyz.de or explicitly for test.xyz.de? It makes some difference even for browsers.

Comment: No I have a Multi-Domain-Cert. It is containing test.xyz.de, service.xyz.de and crm.xyz.de

Comment: By multi domain, do you mean wildcard cert, like my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to export different certificates for those domains:

Check out this tool, really handy comparing to keytool:

http://certman.riaforge.org/

Here's also good post containing how-to for exporting certificates:

http://www.talkingtree.com/blog/index.cfm?mode=entry&entry=25AA75A4-45A6-2844-7CA3EECD842DB576

Comment: Thanks. We ware using the CertMan allready. And I've done the import with the keytool by the tutorial you've linked in your post. It doesn't works :-(

Answer (score 0):

It seems if it's working in ColdFusion 9

Answer (score 0):

Are you running each of the web services off of a different IP address? You can only run one SSL certificate per one IP address: 
http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest you get a wildcard certificate for your domain

*.xyz.de

Then you can use all sorts of combinations over as many servers as you choose.

We do this here, and have no issues with webservices.

Here is the one we use
http://www.digicert.com/wildcard-ssl-certificates.htm